# Silverlight Datagrid : Is it possible to merge row cells horizontally?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, datagrid

I need functionality in data grid like following Record3

Col1    | Col2 | Col3 | Col4

Rec1    | Rec1    | Rec1    | Rec1

Rec2    | Rec2    | Rec2    | Rec2

Record3 Information Appears Horizontally

Rec4    | Rec4    | Rec4    | Rec4

Rec5    | Rec5    | Rec5    | Rec5

Is it possible? Any suggestions?

[image: Cell Merging]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do You have some example view? Any picture or sketch?

Maybe RowDetailsTemplate solve Your problem?
[MSDN - DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

... or check that solution (I don't know that is this bes way to realize this, and especially I don't know how to resolve Your problem wiyhout mixing UI layer and Data layer.
**I think, Your own custom control which realize the code below will be best.**):

**My view:**

Very simple grid, and defined ControlTemplate for DataGridRows (but not assigned in xaml to grid).

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="DataGridRowTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullData}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PageScrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource PageScrollViewerStyle}">
            <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="MySilverlightDataGrid"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            </sdk:DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

**My CodeBehind:**

In scope of method OnNavigatedTo I get the DataGridRowTemplate from view, assign ItemsSource of my grid to employees colection (which was initialized in ctor), then I assigned MySilverlightDataGrid_LoadingRow method to LoadingRow event.

MySilverlightDataGrid_LoadingRow method get the loaded row and his DataContext, then depending on the settings of that DataContext, I set the row template.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            _template = LayoutRoot.Resources["DataGridRowTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
            MySilverlightDataGrid.ItemsSource = _employees;
            MySilverlightDataGrid.LoadingRow += MySilverlightDataGrid_LoadingRow;
        }

        void MySilverlightDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridRow row = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(e.Row);
            var rowEmployee = row.DataContext as Employee;
            if (rowEmployee != null && !rowEmployee.IsEmployeed)
            {
                row.Template = _template;
            }
        }

        private readonly IEnumerable<Employee> _employees;
        private ControlTemplate _template;
```

**Sample model class:**

Of course, it's stupid to fire up GetFullData method, on every time when FullData getter is used, but for this sample is not importand.

```
public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public bool IsEmployeed { get; set; }
        public string FullData
        {
            get
            {
                return GetFullData();
            }
        }

        private string GetFullData()
        {
            return string.Format("Employee data - Name: {0}, Last name: {1}, Age: {2}, City: {3}, Is still employeed: {4}",
                Name, LastName, Age, City,
                (IsEmployeed ? "Yes" : "No"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'll add attachment a few minutes later. If i can't find something then i'll use RowDetailsTemplate.

Comment: Someone added the picture, that's exactly what i need.

Comment: Maybe my second proposition satisfy You...

Comment: Thanks for reply, i resolve it with a very similar way to your approach.